# Anyone know of any resources for someone who wants to learn WPF and F#

Tags: learning, self-improvement, books

It's easy to find resources for learning WPF, similarly it's pretty easy to find resources for F#.

But I feel that I could save some time if I could learn them both at the same time. So can anyone recommend any books, blogs, articles , something else?

(I'm familiar with functional programming, winforms and c#)

Comment: See [What's a good book for learning F#?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/whats-a-good-book-for-learning-f)

Answer (score 2):

**Learning WPF through F#, and vice versa, by John Liao**

 [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsyme/learning-wpf-through-f-and-vice-versa-by-john-liao)

Answer (score 1):

As far as books are concerned I think you'll struggle to find anything - I have most (all?) of the currently available F# books and did a very quick check without much success. Expert F# has about 10 pages on WPF, Beginning F# slightly more. The other books have a couple of mentions of WPF and that's about it.

So...your best bet is probably the series of blog posts by Don Syme (which I see Robert has already linked to in his answer).